# The "ContainerBuildAndLaunch" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: docker, .net-7.0

I'm creating an ASP.Net Core Web API with c#, .Net 7 and docker enabled. When I try to run it using IISExpress, it works great. However, if I try to run it in docker I get below error.

---

Error   MSB4018 The "ContainerBuildAndLaunch" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Containers.Tools.Common.Client.DockerPathHelper.FindDockerCliPath()

---

I tried adding "Microsoft.Win32.Registry" to my packages but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem. Downgrading the NuGet package for ***Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets*** down to 1.11.1, it started giving me actual USEFUL error messages. The main one being I needed to turn on file sharing (*Docker Desktop Settings/Resources/File Sharing*) for my project folder and C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet, though ultimately I just added C:\ to cover everything.

It also said I needed to move my Dockerfile from the root directory (where .sln resides) to the project directory (where .csproj resides).

Now it runs fine. I was even able to upgrade back to 1.15 and it still worked. Would be nice if the newer NuGet versions gave useful errors like the old ones...

Comment: For me, installing the latest version of docker desktop resolved the issue. And yeah also have to add c:\ to make it work. Appreciate your response Matt.